# ksh + argument in PARAM

Tags: shell, ksh

is it posible to print the value `NUM` (`100`) , while I must use only `'` and not `"`

```
 # NUM=100
 # PARAM='some text $NUM'
 # echo $PARAM
   some text $value
```

the right print

```
some text 100
```

Comment: Why MUST you use only single quotes? Variable substitution does not work within single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extremely unsafe, but:  `eval echo $PARAM`

I would strongly advise against this: what if param contains some destructive command in backticks? Either re-think your design or re-think your implementation language.

You could at least escape backticks and `$()` constructs first:

```
NUM=100
PARAM='this is $NUM -- `rm foo` -- $(rm bar)'
param_safer=$(echo "$PARAM" | sed 's/`/\\`/g; s/\$(\([^)]\+\))/\\$\\(\1\\)/g')
eval echo "$param_safer"
```

outputs: `` this is 100 -- `rm foo` -- $(rm bar) ``

Answer (score 1):

Use ***double*** quotes in place of ***single*** quotes as single quotes do not allow variable interpolation:

```
NUM=100
PARAM="some text $NUM"
echo $PARAM
```

**EDIT:** Since I'm not allowed to use double quote, you can use concatenation as:

```
NUM=100
PARAM='some text '$NUM
echo $PARAM
```

Comment: but the main question was about to use single quotes
I cant to use " ,

Comment: I look but the NUM must be in the middle  its not good for me

Comment: @lidia: **in the middle** I don't get it.

Comment: $NUM must be between the single quotes not after the quote

Comment: @lidia: AFAIK that is not possible. Lets wait for more answers.

Comment: @lidia: Why these artificial restrictions?